# How to count number of rows in terms of users id in pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe, it consists many users and their respective actions

[image]

What I need pandas to do is to count the number of rows in terms of user_iD

lets say if user_iD = 1 is repeated 30 or times it should remain in the dataframe otherwise pandas should remove all the user_iD enteries which are less than 30.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could solve your problem.

```py
userid_counts = A.user_iD.value_counts()
mask = userid_counts >= 30
filtered_userids = mask[mask].index

A = A[A.user_iD.isin(filtered_userids)]
```